# How to achieve this style in css without using position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating a HTML page with Bootstrap 4 from an image.
This is the image:

[image]

But i have no idea how to get this style with flexbox.
This is what i have done so far
[image: image2]
html:

```
  <section id="recursos">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="como-funciona text-center">Recursos disponíveis</h1>
      <div class="text-center"><img src="img/linha.png" class="img-fluid">
      <h3 class="ferramenta">Para turbinar o seu negócio no Instagram</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="container-center">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="img/icones/like.png">
        <h3>teste</h3>
        <p>description</p>
        <img src="img/icones/comentario.png">
        <h3>teste</h3>
        <p>description</p>
        <img src="img/icones/relatorio.png">
        <h3>teste</h3>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
      <!-- this is where i was going to put the phone image -->
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      <!-- and here is equal to left elements -->
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>
  </section>
```

css

```
.container-center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
   }

.left{
  width:33.33vw;
  display: inline-grid;
}

.center{
  background:gold;
   width:33.33vw;
}

.right{
  background:gray;
   width:33.33vw;
}
```

Can you guys please help me solve this problem? I dont know how to place the h3 text along with the description like the image.

I'm able to do it using position absolute but i know its not the right way to do it.

Many thanks.

Comment: you can use Flexbox Grid : http://flexboxgrid.com/

Comment: can you explain me how could i use to make it look like the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to provide the exact answer but, I did draw up something that may help you. [image: FlexBox]

Basically, you just need to remember that you can nest flex box elements inside each other.